# How many time will the program calls the increment function when entering the Button control element

Tags: labview

When the user enter the Button control element,how many time will the program calls the increment function?

For this question,i don't know how to calculate the numbers that program calls the 
increment time,the answer is 2,but i don't know the reason,can anyone explain to me?

[image: LabVIEW program]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event case is called when mouse button is clicked on your pane and on your button.

Here, You need to notice that your button is on your pane. It means when mouse down event is happened on your button, in the same time, the event is happened on your pane.

So, when you press down your mouse, Labview will recognize mouse down events are happened twice. one time on your pane and one time on your button.